# The if/else in background script does not execute on extension click but only after unpacked extension refresh

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest

I'm trying to load a background script (extension-starter.js) that contains an if/else statement. I store a user's preference for how to open the extension (popup, new window, new tab) in local storage. Upon opening the extension, I expect it to retrieve the saved value and open the extension appropriately, but for some reason when changing the preference (for example from popup to new tab), clicking the extension icon opens the extension in the previous state. Only after I refresh the unpacked extension does it open the app as expected.

```
    // Here is the manifest.json...(took out unnecessary info)
    {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["extension-starter.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {}
}
    // Here is the extension-starter.js...
    const extPrefer = localStorage.getItem('extensionPreference');

    if (extPrefer === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('extensionPreference', 'popup');
    }

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    if (extPrefer === 'window') {
        chrome.windows.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"), width: 500, height: 600});
    }
    else if (extPrefer === 'tab') {
        chrome.tabs.create({url:chrome.extension.getURL("index.html")});
    }
    else {
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
        popup: "index.html"
    });
    }
    })
```

I expect to retrieve the saved preference from local storage and open the extension in the desired manner.

---

**UPDATE**
The above issue is caused by `chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "index.html"});`. Once the `setPopup` is executed, I cannot update back to window or tab preference. It seems like `setPopup` is being set on the manifest and cannot be overwritten when changing the preference from popup to tab or window.

**Updated Question:**
1. Is there a way to do the opposite of `setPopup`?
2. Is there another method for `setPopup`?

Comment: I would check and see what the value of `localStorage.getItem('extensionPreference')` is inside your onClick function. Maybe the value is getting cached?

Comment: Good point @JamesWasson, but unfortunately, console.logs from script's body and inside the click callback to do not persist to the console, which is super weird. Checking localStorage I can ensure the value is updated, and persists upon extension's relaunch.

Comment: Okay, was being a bit of a dunce. I see the console.log but only once, one outside of the function and one inside the callback function. If I add a removeListener, the extension only opens once.

Comment: So this is fixed then?

Comment: No, I meant in regards to not seeing the console.log. I see the console.log now but they only execute once, meaning the entire script executed only once. Sorry for the confusion but the initial issue is still very real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out! Below I will explain the ultimate issue and then, the solution.

**Issue**

In the background script, I wanted to allow a saved value in `localStorage` to determine whether the extension opens as a popup, a new window, or a new tab. Switching between window and tab worked, except when switching from popup. If popup is selected, the extension would open as a popup. When switching to new tab, for example, the extension would still open as a popup. The new value would only work after restarting the extension. The issue was in, *drumroll please*:

`chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "index.html"});`.

**Solution**

I am not sure as to the exact cause of the issue above (and I don't want to just say things that may be false or not 100% accurate) but the simple solution was executing the `setPopup` method on a tab rather than the browser.

**First**, in the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` method's callback function pass in `tab`.
`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {`

**Second**, set the `setPopup` to execute on the tab by doing the following...
`chrome.browserAction.setPopup({tabId: tab.id, popup: "index.html"});`

The above solution works like a charm. If anything is not clear, please let me know! Thanks **JamesWasson** for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this a tell me how it goes:

```
    if (localStorage.getItem('extensionPreference') === null) {
        localStorage.setItem('extensionPreference', 'popup');
    }

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
        // move this inside the click function
        const extPrefer = localStorage.getItem('extensionPreference');

        if (extPrefer === 'window') {
            chrome.windows.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html"), width: 500, height: 600 });
        }
        else if (extPrefer === 'tab') {
            chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL("index.html") });
        }
        else {
            chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
                popup: "index.html"
            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: The behavior is exactly the same. When adding console.logs outside and inside callback, it only executes once. Requires refreshing the extension for the changes to be picked up. I do see a `TypeError: Request scheme 'chrome-extension' is unsupported` error, but the console.logs still execute. Maybe worth getting rid of the error before moving on to figuring this out.

Comment: Removed `registerServiceWorker` so no more errors, but the initial issue still persists.

Comment: Okay, I think I found the culprit: `chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "index.html"});`. Without this statement, I can switch between tab and window without issue. I think `setPopup` actually sets it in the manifest, and if it's there, other methods for opening the app do not work! So the question now is, how do I remove the `setPopup`?